# Append text before number in LibreOffice Calc

Tags: append, libreoffice-calc

How to append text before number in LibreOffice Calc?

For example, I got this:

> Some text 2 l
> Some another text 1 l

and I want to get this:

> Some text **appended_text** 2 l
> Some another text **appended_text** 1 l

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use regular expressions in search/replace:

1. Select the cells that should get modified;
2. Open find/replace: Menu "`Edit`" -> "`Find/Replace...`" or <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
3. Open "`Other options`" at the bottom of the Find/Replace dialog;
4. Make sure "`Regular Expressions`" is selected;
5. In the "`Search for`" box, enter

   > [:digit:]+
6. In the "`Replace with`" box, enter

   > appendend_text $0
7. Execute the Find/Replace.

This will append the string `appended_text` to every numerical value inside the selected cells. It should also work if there are more than one digit (for example, `Some another text 15` is changed to `Some another text appendend_text 15`). The regex is extremly simple: it just matches every numerical value.

Comment: Thanks!

Work like a charm!